# Variable does not equal variable when it should in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, http, if-statement, webserver

I am making my first web server, but When i use the if statement to compare user input from html file with a string, they just skip it even if it is true.

```
require 'socket'
require 'pry'

class Parser

  def parse(req, clients)

    save = File.new("requests.txt", "w+")
    save.write(req.chomp)
    save.close
    words = IO.readlines("requests.txt").last(1)
    if words == "Username=test&Password=1234"
      success(clients)
    end
    #binding.pry

    puts words

  end
end

def success(succ_client)

  success_file = File.read("templates/success.html")
  stuff = "HTTP/1.1 200\r\n" + success_file.force_encoding('UTF-8')
  succ_client.puts(stuff)

end

def response(cli)

  file = File.read("templates/passpage.html")
  content = "HTTP/1.1 200\r\n" + file.force_encoding('UTF-8')
  cli.puts(content)

end

serv_sock = TCPServer.new('10.0.2.15', 8080)

loop {
  client = serv_sock.accept()
  requests = Parser.new
  requests.parse(client.readpartial(2043), client)
  response(client)

  client.close
  puts "Connected"
}
```

I tried using #compact!, nil?, and using pry to decode to find whats the issue, but I just cant find the problem, when i puts the words variable it puts the correct value but its just not the right one I guess. I tried decoding the words but that still didn't work unless i did it wrong.
It has been 5 days on this problem and this is my first ruby program, and web-server, So ill appreciate any help I can get with this to move forward in life.

Comment: Please include some actual content. It's hard to say whether two values are equal (or even equivalent) without actual debugging output of the values. In addition, URI or character encoding issues, or even line endings, may play a part. Without being able to see the actual and expected data for comparison, it's a guessing game. Use Kernel#pp or String#inspect to give us something more to work with.

Comment: Thanks, but when I use #inspect and pp they just output to " ["Username=hello&Password=world"]  " and nothing else. When I use pry gem it would output ``` 
[1] pry(#<Parser>)> puts words
Username=test&Password=1234
=> nil
```

Comment: By definition, #puts always returns nil. So, comparing anything to a return value of `nil` except nil will fail. Secondly, since you're getting two different strings, I'm not sure why you think the strings should match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

Primarily, your call to `IO.readlines("requests.txt").last(1)` returns an Array of zero or one strings. However, you are comparing it to a single  string. Since the string is not equal to the array, the comparison fails.

Likely, you want to use `IO.readlines("requests.txt").last` instead. This returns the last element or the array or `nil` if the array returned by the `readlines` method is empty.

Please have a look at the [documentation of the `Array#last` method](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Array.html#method-i-last) to learn more about the returned types of this method.

In addition to that, even if your `if` statement eventually matches, your intended call to the `success` method fill fail, because you have defined it in the global `main` object, rather than your `Parser` class.

Also, when you eventually call `success` from your `parse` method, you will be returning two responses as you also call the `response` method later. You may want to rethink the way you select the correct responses...

Comment: Thank you, I have looked at and done everything you said and it is working as attended. Thank you for your time, and elite skills, I am very grateful.